# Agrupar elementos de un arreglo

Tags: array, c, pilas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intentando cargar "4 | 2 | -1 | 5 | 7 | 9 | -2 | 4 ..." en el arreglo, permite cargar hasta el 5 y se detiene. ¿Cuál sería mi error?

Inicializo **A[17], int validos, valor, cdad, suma, i = 0** y **char control = 's'** para más tarde darle la opción al usuario de frenar la carga de valores.

```
while (control == 's' && validos < 18)
{
    printf("Ingrese valor: ");
    scanf("%i", &valor);
    A[i] = valor;

    if (A[i] < 0)
    {
        i++;
        printf("Ingrese valor: ");
        scanf("%i", &valor);
        A[i] = valor;
        do
        {
            suma = suma + A[i];
            cdad++;
        }
        while (A[i] > 0);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Si estás empezando a programar no intentes hacer todo de una sola vez hazlo por partes, te aconsejo que primero los agrupes en un array multidimensional y luego simplemente recorras ese array y calcules los resultados